# How can I perform arithmetic operation taking a integer and string as input

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I am taking a integer input from a function and the operation such as "+10" from the user and printing the result after computation. So far i have this

```
def Eval(arg1, arg2):

    if (arg1 >= 100):
        arg1 == 100
    else:
        arg1 = eval((arg1)(arg2))
        print arg1
Eval(10,'+10')
```

But I have `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable error`. Can someone tell me where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`. This is recommended instead of `eval` due to security concerns.

```
from ast import literal_eval

def Eval(arg1, arg2):

    if (arg1 >= 100):
        arg1 == 100

    return literal_eval(str(arg1)+arg2)

x = raw_input('Append string to variable for calculation:\n')  # '+10'
res = Eval(10, x)

print res  # 20
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from attempting to pass `eval` an `int` and a `str` when it only accepts a `str`. You could solve this by combining arg1 and arg2, after converting arg1 to a `str`.

```
arg1 = 10
arg2 = '+1'
evalInput = str(arg1) + arg2
eval(evalInput)
>> 11
```

This could be made cleaner by using string formatting, but this should give you a general idea.